# The idea of tangent plane and optimal local linearization

Tags: calculus, integration, area

My initial thoughts:Suppose we have a Cartesian coordinate system $(X,Y,Z)$and a function F(x,y).I know its tangent line or tangent plane information is given by $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{x}}$and $\frac{\partial{F}}{\partial{y}}$

---

But I don’t understand the optimal linearization of parametric equations.
[Picture in the video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Roq9A.png)

$\vec {r}(s,t)=x(x,t)\hat{i}+y(s,t)\hat{j}+z(s,t)\hat{k}$

Its local linearization in xyz Cartesian coordinates is $\Delta \vec{r}(s+\Delta{s},t)=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial{s}}\Delta {s}$and$\Delta \vec{r}(s,t+\Delta{t})=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial{t}}\Delta {t}$

I'm sorry, I didn't receive a strict education.Maybe I think it's like a straight line in the smallest change.But this can't convince me.Because its information is not given by $\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial{x}}$ and $\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial{y}}$

---

Question:
Is there any reason to think that the change caused by $s$ and $t$ can be the best linearization in the xyz Cartesian coordinate system,Can it be considered a tangent?

---

I can use parametric variables to describe the approach process and not necessarily the ratio of y and x.

[Geometric intuition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chon9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the local linearization you've described gives the best linear approximation of $\vec r$ at $(s,t)$, and it is a parametrization of the tangent plane (as long as $\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial s}$ and $\frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial t}$ are linearly independent vectors).

Are you having trouble visualizing the situation? It might help to think about the 2-dimensional version: a parametric curve $\vec r(t)=x(t)\hat i+y(t)\hat j$. Moving a small distance along the curve corresponds to a small change $\Delta t$ and resulting changes $\Delta x\approx\frac{dx}{dt}\Delta t$ and $\Delta y\approx\frac{dy}{dt}\Delta t$. The "slope" of this segment of the curve is $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\frac{(dy/dt)\Delta t}{(dx/dt)\Delta t}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$. If the same curve is the graph of a function $y(x)$, then we also have $\Delta y\approx\frac{dy}{dx}\Delta x$, so $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\frac{dy}{dx}$. In other words, the derivatives in $\frac {d\vec r}{dt}$ and the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$ describe the same linear relationship between small changes in $x$ and $y$.

In 3D, it's essentially the same idea, but there are two parameters so that we can move in two independent directions on the surface. You might also be interested in the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem).

Comment: So touched,thank you for your help! I don’t know what other possible descriptions are？I also found another explanation. From a geometric intuition, it is also possible to use parametric variables to describe proximity.I added a picture to the question above